# Xcode is not working on my mac after downloading multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to download xcode because I want homebrew to work on my mac.
Whenever I start the download, it works but when I open the extension, there is a cross sign on the logo which indicates that the file cannot be opened.
I tried to download different versions, but nothing has worked. I have tried to reboot my system and everything else I can think of. 
Pls help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of your mac OS X version not support the latest version of Xcode.

You need to download the latest version of mac OS X.